# Windows Store App HttpClient progress

Tags: http, windows-10-universal

I need to provide the download progress inside the app for an arbitrary file.
I thought I could use [HttpClient.GetInputStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.getinputstreamasync.aspx) progress but it is not fine grained. The progress notification is delivered very rare. The code below:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var path = new Uri(@"http://<path>");

using (var inputStream = (await httpClient.GetInputStreamAsync(path).AsTask(new MyProgress())).AsStreamForRead())
{
    var outputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("output.mov", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var outputStream = (await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)).AsStreamForWrite())
    {
        await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);

        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}

Debug.WriteLine("done");


private class MyProgress : IProgress<HttpProgress>
{
    public void Report(HttpProgress value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("HTTP {0} progress {1}/{2}", value.Stage, value.BytesReceived, value.TotalBytesToReceive);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
HTTP ResolvingName progress 0/
HTTP ConnectingToServer progress 0/
HTTP SendingHeaders progress 0/
HTTP WaitingForResponse progress 0/
HTTP ReceivingHeaders progress 0/
HTTP ReceivingContent progress 0/109192147
done
```

So at some point of time the total bytes to receive is known but no progress reported during file download.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with solution like below:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var path = new Uri(@"http://<path>");

var progressHelper = new ProgressHelper();

using (var inputStream = (await httpClient.GetInputStreamAsync(path).AsTask(progressHelper)).AsStreamForRead())
{
    var outputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("output.mov", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var outputStream = (await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)).AsStreamForWrite())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            progressHelper.BytesReceived += (ulong)read;

            await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}

Debug.WriteLine("done");


private class ProgressHelper : IProgress<HttpProgress>
{
    private ulong _bytesReceived = 0;
    private ulong? _totalBytesToReceive = null;

    public void Report(HttpProgress value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("HTTP {0} progress {1}/{2}", value.Stage, value.BytesReceived, value.TotalBytesToReceive);

        TotalBytesToReceive = value.TotalBytesToReceive;                
    }

    public ulong? TotalBytesToReceive
    {
        get
        {
            return _totalBytesToReceive;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_totalBytesToReceive == value)
                return;

            _totalBytesToReceive = value;
            UpdateProgress();
        }
    }

    public ulong BytesReceived
    {
        get
        {
            return _bytesReceived;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_bytesReceived == value)
                return;

             _bytesReceived = value;
            UpdateProgress();
        }
    }

    public int? Progress
    {
        get
        {
            if (_totalBytesToReceive.HasValue)
            {
                return (int)Math.Round((100.0 * _bytesReceived) / _totalBytesToReceive.Value);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateProgress()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Progress: {0}", Progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: You new a buffer yourself,this code is apply a  space from memory and as download buffer in memory. it is still consume the memory. What you write is just wrapped by the HttpClient API

Answer (score 0):

Since the `HttpClient.GetInputStreamAsync` doesn't support progress during file download, you can use other methods of `HttpClient` such as `GetAsync` and`GetBufferAsync`.The following code is updating of your code to use `HttpClient.GetAsync`.

```
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var path = new Uri("https://sec.ch9.ms/slides/developerGuideToWindows10/02-XAMLcontrols.pptx");
  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(path).AsTask(new MyProgress());
  using (Stream responseStream = (await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()).AsStreamForRead())
  {
      var outputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("output.pptx", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
      using (var outputStream = (await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)).AsStreamForWrite())
      {
          await responseStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
          await outputStream.FlushAsync();
      }
  }
  Debug.WriteLine("done");
```

And the outputs

[image]

Comment: It does report the progress, however it also load the all content into memory which is what I would like to avoid. Sorry for late answer, was busy.